# Unity Top-Down Dashing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

Trying to Create Dash feature to my top-down game and when I press space I can see the velocity changing by looking at the console but in actual gameplay it won't change a bit.
What am I missing? I know there's a lot of lines that are not mature enough but please focus on the feature of a dash function.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const float DOUBLE_TAP_TIMELIMIT = 0.2f;
    public float walkSpeed = 5f;
    public float sprintSpeed = 10f;

    private bool canDash = true;
    private bool isDashing;
    public float dashingPower = 24f;
    private float dashingTime = 0.2f;
    private float dashingCoolDown = 1f;

    private Rigidbody2D rigid;
    public TrailRenderer tr;
    private float horz;
    private float vert;
    private bool HorV;
    private bool isSprinting=false;

    void Awake()
    {
        rigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        tr = GetComponent<TrailRenderer>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(isDashing){
            return ;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
            isSprinting = true;
        else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift))
            isSprinting = false;

        horz = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        vert = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        bool hDown = Input.GetButtonDown("Horizontal");
        bool hUp = Input.GetButtonUp("Horizontal");
        bool vDown = Input.GetButtonDown("Vertical");
        bool vUp = Input.GetButtonUp("Vertical");

        //Disallowing Diagonal Movement
        if (hDown || vUp)
            HorV = true;
        else if (vDown || hUp)
            HorV = false;

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && canDash)
            StartCoroutine(Dash());
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (!isSprinting)
        {   //Walking
            if (HorV)
                rigid.velocity = new Vector2(horz, 0) * walkSpeed;
            else
                rigid.velocity = new Vector2(0, vert) * walkSpeed;
        }
        else
        {   //Sprinting
            if (HorV)
                rigid.velocity = new Vector2(horz, 0) * sprintSpeed;
            else
                rigid.velocity = new Vector2(0, vert) * sprintSpeed;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator Dash() {
        canDash = false;
        isDashing = true;
        if(HorV)
            rigid.velocity = new Vector2(horz,0)*dashingPower;
        else 
            rigid.velocity = new Vector2(0,vert)*dashingPower;
        Debug.Log(rigid.velocity);
        tr.emitting = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(dashingTime);
        tr.emitting = false;
        isDashing = false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(dashingCoolDown);
        canDash = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding Force instead of settings the velocity, i.e. `rigid.AddForce(Vector2(horz,0)*dashingPower)`. You can also change ForceMode to Impulse.

Comment: It still won't dash. Staying at the same velocity ethernity

Comment: Tried dashing at the Update and it works totally fine saying nothing wrong with the GameObject. Gotta look closer to the dash function.

Comment: you set for walk of sprint in fixedupdate, id guess its overwriting it

Comment: Thanks. Replacing Dash activation code under the walk/sprint fixed it.